# How to disable shift key on startup in xp?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, msconfig, gpedit

as you know, in windows xp, there is a hidden option

to temporarily stop running startup programs, you can easily hold down the shift key

is there a way to disable this option?

i have searched the internet but i didn't find a way

Answer (score 0):

From TweakLibrary, using 'regedit' (use 'Enabled' value):

Registry Entry 1 : [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]

Key Type : Local Machine

Value Name : IgnoreShiftOveride

Data Type : DWORD (DWORD Value)

Enabled Value : 1

Disabled value : 0

http://win.tweaklibrary.com/System/Startup-and-Shutdown/60/Set/Disable-the-shift-key-during-the-boot-process-to-skip-programs/10701/

Comment: I have tested it but not working in windows xp sp2... anyway tnx for your time :)